# Overlay a background using pattern in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have used the following css file to over background `bg.jpg` with a `repeat-x repeat-y` pattern of `dots.png`.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #666;
    font-family: comfortaa;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height:1.5em; 
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 17%;
    background: url(../images/header.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
#dots{  
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:transparent url(../images/dots.png) repeat-x repeat-y top left;
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

Then I wrote the index.php like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My test page</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="header"></div>
   Under Construction
   <div id="dots"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the pattern is not overlaying. What can I do to resolve this? Please help.

Comment: You'll help us out if you prepare a jsfiddle.net for us. And someone just recently told me about placekitten for demo backgrounds :)

Comment: Thanks for the vote, I was wondering if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just { background: repeat; }, not -x and -y.

http://jsfiddle.net/XNeDK/

Comment: still no luck. repeat-x and repeat-y is ok with css by the way

Comment: Did it work on the jsfiddle link I provided? As Liyan mentioned below, using *both* -x and -y is not valid CSS. repeat is the default, but if you are overriding something else you will need it of course.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
background:transparent url(../images/dots.png) repeat-x repeat-y top left;
```

to:

```
background:transparent url(../images/dots.png) top left;
```

The default behavior is to repeat both x and y; giving it both parameters is actually incorrect.

Here's a JSFiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XsDjy/

Answer (score 1):

`Height: 100%` is like `0px` if you don't fill something inside the div... so I suggest you to give a fixed height, `1px` as well will be enough to see the dots.

Comment: still no luck, i made the height 1px, width 1px. even tried with 1024px

Comment: remove `repeat-x`, `repeat-y` and add only `repeat`.